# How to move URL parameters to the filename using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How do I make URL look like the following, using Apache's `.htaccess` file?

I want to convert from:

```
http://site.com/users/?a=james31
```

to:

```
http://site.com/users/james31
```

Comment: use `mod_rewrite` if it's apache and RewriteRule command

Comment: I can't see how, especially using the right regexp